# How can I make pagination for my dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My table is created with dynamic OO javascript and now I have to make pagination for rows - something like 5 rows(users) on the page :-? Also I need to display the pagination numbers when there are more than 5 users  ...
  This is the pice of code that make the display of the table :

```
(function (window) {

function ListView(store) {
    var me = this;
    this.store = store;
    this.defaultTemplate = '<tr data-id = "{{id}}">' +
        '<td><button class = "edit btna" type="button"></button>' +
        '<button class = "delete btna" type="button" ></button></td>' +
        '<td class = "userCol">' + '{{username}}' + '</td>' +
        '<td class = "levelCol">' + '{{level}}' + '</td>' +
        '<td class = "regCol">' + "<img src='img/" + '{{regstatus}}' + "_registered.png'>" + '</td>' +
        '<td class = "dateCol">' + '{{regdate}}' + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';

    $(this.store).on("storeLoad", function () {
        var data = this.getUsers();
        me.show(data);
    });
}

ListView.prototype.show = function (data) {
    var i, l;
    var view = '';
    for (i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
        var template = this.defaultTemplate;
        template = template.replace('{{id}}', data[i].id);
        template = template.replace('{{username}}', data[i].username);
        template = template.replace('{{level}}', data[i].level);
        template = template.replace('{{regstatus}}', data[i].regstatus);
        template = template.replace('{{regdate}}', data[i].regdate);
        view = view + template;
    }
    console.log(data);
    $('#userList').html(view);
};

// Export to window
window.app.ListView = ListView;
})(window);
```

Any ideeas ?

Comment: Seems like you might be re-inventing the wheel.  Would [Bootstrap Data-Tables](http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) be a viable option for you?  It handles pagnation for you, and is fully customizable.

Comment: yes thats the point :) i want to see what is happening and how can be done :) its not about copy/paste i want to actualy learn how can be created ...

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: i have data(my users)  in my function and i dont know how to put the condition to show only 5 data(users) and hide he other ones and when i click on the pagination number to show the rest..:-?